# how to minimize database latency issues for increase sharepoint web front end servers issues

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-farm

how to minimize database latency issues for increase sharepoint web front end and applications servers performance
I have a large scale of sharepoint farm and in peak time there is issue of Sql server slowness

Comment: You must first identify the actual bottleneck before addressing it. "Latency" is a generic term which could mean network, disk, CPU, memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to check consider:

- Add RAM to SQL Server box
- Decrease the distance between the SQL Server and the SharePoint servers
- Isolate the SQL Server from other applications--just have SharePoint databases on one server, no other instances or non-SharePoint application databases
- Point the web servers back to themselves (127.0.0.1) in the HOSTS file.
- Decrease the services on the web front end servers that should be application server specific.
- Add more servers to the farm and scale out.
- [Follow the recommended requirements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt493254(v=office.16).aspx)